# PVRTC2 texture compression on iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es

Imagination Technologies released an OpenGL ES 2.0 extension called [IMG_texture_compression_pvrtc2](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/IMG/IMG_texture_compression_pvrtc2.txt) almost five years ago that offers image quality improvements over PVRTC1 compression. A detailed article is found [here](https://www.imgtec.com/blog/pvrtc2-taking-texture-compression-to-a-new-dimension/),

I know that iOS support PVRTC1 compression, and it is listed in extensions on all devices. Does anyone know if Apple supports PVRTC2 or plans to in the near future? Since the extension has been out for so long, Apple recommends PVRTC over other formats, and I assume their hardware already supports, It seems like the should.

Does anyone know of any mobile platform that supports this extension? Any additional information would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know if Apple supports PVRTC2

Doesn't look like it.

> or plans to in the near future?

You'd have to ask Apple.

> Does anyone know of any mobile platform that supports this extension?

It's an IMG proprietary extension and texture format, so you'd have to try and find a non-Apple device with a recent high-end IMG GPU.

You'd probably have more luck looking at the ASTC texture format; that one is a multi-vendor extension (and mandatory in OpenGL ES 3.2 so widely supported).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I assumed as much. I am looking for a concrete answer to those very questions. Did Apple make any comment on the issue? Was it ever announced, or discussed in mailing lists, etc.  What specific devices have those GPUs? Ill also look into ASTC.

Comment: Apple very rarely discuss anything in public in my experience. Given their public statement to move away from IMG in the next 18 months, it seems unlikely they are going to implement an IMG proprietary extension any time soon though; recommending developers move to ASTC seems much more plausible.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I'm pretty sure the Sony Vita has exposed PVRTC2 however I've no idea why Apple didn't as it's been in the HW for a long time.